# Lasagne package issue

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, lasagne

In Conda prompt it shows resolving metadata and then in the solving environment it takes lots of time & shows error saying it couldn't perform by frozen method so tries for dynamic pan but still not executed.

**How can I install the `lasagne` package in Anaconda?**

Comment: Please show the error you are getting by pasting the text into your question

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a Python version issue. The Lasagne Python package has not been updated in a few years, and therefore the only versions of Python it is compatible with are 2.7, 3.4, and 3.5 (see [available files on Anaconda Cloud](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/lasagne/files)).  Any relatively recent installations of Anaconda are likely not using any of these versions and changing the Python version in your **base** env is not recommended - hence why it likely fails to solve.  Instead, create a new environment specifically for Lasagne, e.g.,

```
conda create -n my_lasagne_env lasagne
```

Then you can use this env with `conda activate my_lasagne_env`.

Generally, the best practice in Conda is to create a new environment for each project or project type, and minimize updating or adding new packages after you have the packages required for the development project.  This includes not avoiding making changes to your **base** env, aside from the occasional `conda update conda` to make sure the package manager itself stays up to date.

Answer (score 0):

To install this package with conda run:

`conda install -c toli lasagne`

Solving environment look at [Here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8051)

If not you can find solution : https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7690